# Can't show image from firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to display an image stored in the firestore but an having problems

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class UsersViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var userData: UserProfileData?
    
    init(){
        fetchCurrentUser()
    }
    
    private func fetchCurrentUser(){
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else{return}
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error{
                print(error)
                self.errorMessage = "Can get current User ID"
                return
            }
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else{
                self.errorMessage = "No data found"
                return}
            //            self.errorMessage = "\(data)"
            let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            let username = data["username"] as? String ?? "Username"
            let imageURl = data["imageURl"] as? String ?? ""
            let posts = data["posts"] as? String ?? ""
            let followers = data["followers"] as? String ?? ""
            let following = data["following"] as? String ?? ""
            let bio  = data["bio"] as? String ?? "Bio"
            self.userData = UserProfileData(id: uid, uid: uid, username: username, imageURl: imageURl, posts: posts, followers: followers, following: following, bio: bio)
        }
    }
}
```

here is some sample code of where I show the data

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct Profile: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var ViewModel = UsersViewModel()

    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                VStack{
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: ViewModel.userData?.imageURl ?? ""))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(64)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                    
                    Text(ViewModel.userData?.username ?? "")
                        .padding()
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                    Followers()
                    Bio()
                        .padding(.top)
```

the thing is that I can see the username perfectly fine but the image does not show

here is UserProfileData

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserProfileData: Identifiable, Codable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var uid: String
    var username: String
    var imageURl: String
    var posts: String
    var followers:  String
    var following: String
    var bio: String
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my error?
many thanks

Comment: Change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`.

Comment: it didn't make a difference

Comment: Well then try to post a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper URL from Firebase?

Comment: yes I do have the proper URL